# Feasibilty analysis of data transformation using any ETL tool

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, oracle-data-integrator, ibm-infosphere

I don't have any experience on any ETL tool. However I want to know if it is possible to do the followings using any ETL tool or we need to write a java or any other batch job to do this:

**Scenario 1:**
The source system has different REST APIs. I need to get the data, transform it, then store the data in a MongoDB. 
The hardest part is the transformation. There can be situation where I need to call a REST API of source, and based on its data I need to call several other REST APIs using the 1st API data. After that we need to format the entire data in different format and store it in Mongo.

**Scenario 2:**
The source system has a DB. I need to transform the data using my custom logic and store it in MongoDB.
Here the custom logic can include things like this:
From table1 of source I created collection1. After that I need to consult table2 and previously created collection1, process the data and then create collection2.

Is this possible using any ETL tool? If possible then which tool? If possible please mention in as short as possible, how it can be done using different terminology so that I can search internet, learn things and implement it.

Comment: did you end up with an ETL tool? if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly speaking: yes, that is what ETL tools are exactly for. You can Extract data from REST sources, Transform using sophisticated logic and Load to target, like MongoDB.

Exact implementation depends on the tool. While I guess you will get help if you run across problems implementing the solution in any of the tools, I don't think anyone will prepare complete, detailed solutions for you.